# How do I exchange my follower for another one?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the Vampire Serana following me and I don't want to sacrifice her for the Bohethia Calling quest. When I try to hire someone else e.g. from pubs in cities, they say "it looks like you already have someone" even if I ask Serana to wait at my house. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

Don't tell your follower to "wait" tell them to "part ways". They will then return to a predetermined location (usually where you found them) where they can be picked up later (many followers tell you where).

Comment: Serana in particular will generally return to either Castle Volkihar or the Dawnguard fort (whatever it's called).  Since she's essential, I doubt she *can* be sacrificed in any event.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to her and choose "part ways" option. After that, you can hire other followers for sacrifice (I choose Stenvar from Candle Hearth Windhelm for this). After you are done with Boethiah Quest, then you can invite Serana in Fort Dawnguard. Good luck